# Listener "SoftDeleteableListener" was not added to the EventManager

Tags: doctrine-orm, soft-delete, symfony-2.1

I followed the [this example](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/softdeleteable.md) to test `softdeletable` extension on my project running Symfony 2.1.0-DEV.

I configured my config.yml like below:

```
orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
    auto_mapping: true
    filters:
          softdeleteable:
            class: Gedmo\SoftDeleteable\Filter\SoftDeleteableFilter
            enabled: true
    mappings:
        translatable:
            type: annotation
            alias: Gedmo
            prefix: Gedmo\Translatable\Entity
            # make sure vendor library location is correct
            dir: "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/gedmo/doctrine-extensions/lib/Gedmo/Translatable/Entity"
        loggable:
            type: annotation
            alias: Gedmo
            prefix: Gedmo\Loggable\Entity
            dir: "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/gedmo/doctrine-extensions/lib/Gedmo/Loggable/Entity"
        tree:
            type: annotation
            alias: Gedmo
            prefix: Gedmo\Tree\Entity
            dir: "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/gedmo/doctrine-extensions/lib/Gedmo/Tree/Entity"
```

My controller action:

```php
/**
 * @Route("/del", name="del_article")
 */
public function delAction() {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

    $article = $em->find('Article', 3);
    $em->remove($article);
            $em->flush();
    die('ok');
}
```

When I run the code, it always show the exception: `Listener "SoftDeleteableListener" was not added to the EventManager!`

After some time spent with debugging, I found that the class `SoftDeleteableFilter` has function `getListener()`:

```php
protected function getListener()
{
    if ($this->listener === null) {
        $em = $this->getEntityManager();
        $evm = $em->getEventManager();

        foreach ($evm->getListeners() as $listeners) {
            foreach ($listeners as $listener) {
                if ($listener instanceof SoftDeleteableListener) {
                    $this->listener = $listener;

                    break 2;
                }
            }
        }

        if ($this->listener === null) {
            throw new \RuntimeException('Listener "SoftDeleteableListener" was not added to the EventManager!');
        }
    }

    return $this->listener;
}
```

However `$listeners` property has no `SoftDeleteableListener` item, but it has other listeners, such as

- Gedmo\Tree\TreeListener
- Gedmo\Sortable\SortableListener
- Gedmo\Sluggable\SluggableListener
- Gedmo\Loggable\LoggableListener
- Gedmo\Timestampable\TimestampableListener
- Gedmo\Translatable\TranslatableListener

Which are generated from loadClassMetadata. I think it might generate from my doctrine_extensions.yml service listener:

```
services:
    extension.listener:
        class: Infinitz\UserBundle\Listener\DoctrineExtensionListener
        calls:
            - [ setContainer, [ @service_container ] ]
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onLateKernelRequest, priority: -10 }
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onKernelRequest }
    gedmo.listener.tree:
        class: Gedmo\Tree\TreeListener
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_subscriber, connection: default }
        calls:
            - [ setAnnotationReader, [ @annotation_reader ] ]

    gedmo.listener.translatable:
        class: Gedmo\Translatable\TranslatableListener
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_subscriber, connection: default }
        calls:
            - [ setAnnotationReader, [ @annotation_reader ] ]
            - [ setDefaultLocale, [ %locale% ] ]
            - [ setTranslationFallback, [ false ] ]

    gedmo.listener.timestampable:
        class: Gedmo\Timestampable\TimestampableListener
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_subscriber, connection: default }
        calls:
            - [ setAnnotationReader, [ @annotation_reader ] ]

    gedmo.listener.sluggable:
        class: Gedmo\Sluggable\SluggableListener
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_subscriber, connection: default }
        calls:
            - [ setAnnotationReader, [ @annotation_reader ] ]

    gedmo.listener.sortable:
        class: Gedmo\Sortable\SortableListener
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_subscriber, connection: default }
        calls:
            - [ setAnnotationReader, [ @annotation_reader ] ]

    gedmo.listener.loggable:
        class: Gedmo\Loggable\LoggableListener
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_subscriber, connection: default }
        calls:
            - [ setAnnotationReader, [ @annotation_reader ] ]
```

So I tried to add following:

```
gedmo.listener.softdeleteable:
    class: Gedmo\SoftDeleteable\SoftDeleteableListener
    tags:
        - { name: doctrine.event_subscriber, connection: default }
    calls:
        - [ setAnnotationReader, [ @annotation_reader ] ]
```

But it still shows `Listener "SoftDeleteableListener" was not added to the EventManager!`

Do I need to add an listener which instance of SoftDeleteableListener?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Couldn't solve problem because of unclear answer.

To add softdeletable behaviour to your project add following lines to your config.yml

```
orm
  ..
  filters:
    softdeleteable:
      class: Gedmo\SoftDeleteable\Filter\SoftDeleteableFilter
      enabled: true

services:
  ..
  gedmo.listener.softdeleteable:
    class: Gedmo\SoftDeleteable\SoftDeleteableListener
    tags:
        - { name: doctrine.event_subscriber, connection: default }
    calls:
        - [ setAnnotationReader, [ '@annotation_reader' ] ]
```

Btw, more complete discussion, which helped me, can be found: https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/issues/380

Comment: I got " Uncaught Symfony\Component\Yaml\Exception\ParseException: The reserved indicator "@" cannot start a plain scalar; you need to quote the scalar", I had to quote: [ "@annotation_reader" ]

Comment: Thanks alot, you have saved a day

Answer (score 16):

See: https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.rst#activate-the-extensions-you-want

Add the following to your config.yml to activate the softdelete listener:

```
# app/config.yml
stof_doctrine_extensions:
    default_locale: %locale%
    orm:
        default:
            softdeleteable: true
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are on api-platform
This is my `config/packages/doctrine.yml`

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'

        # IMPORTANT: You MUST configure your server version,
        # either here or in the DATABASE_URL env var (see .env file)
        server_version: '12'
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
        auto_mapping: true
        mappings:
            App:
                is_bundle: false
                type: annotation
                dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                prefix: 'App\Entity'
                alias: App
        filters:
            softdeleteable:
                class: Gedmo\SoftDeleteable\Filter\SoftDeleteableFilter
                enabled: true
```

after that add the new service to `config.services.yml`

```
services:   
    ..........
    ..........
    gedmo.listener.softdeleteable:
        class: Gedmo\SoftDeleteable\SoftDeleteableListener
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_subscriber, connection: default }
        calls:
            - [ setAnnotationReader, [ '@annotation_reader' ] ]
```

Finally add the annotation to the `entity`

```
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;

/**
* @ApiResource()
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=StoreRepository::class)
* @ORM\Table(name="trn_stores")
* @Gedmo\SoftDeleteable(fieldName="deletedAt")
*/
class Store ...
```

That's it

Answer (score 0):

sorry about my carelessness, because I overwrote my configuration in config.yml file at the bottom of the file use:

```
services:
    gedmo.listener.softdeleteable:
        class:        Gedmo\SoftDeleteable\SoftDeleteableListener
```

and did not configure properly..... now the problem has been fixed.